# How to save a dictionary containing utf-8 characters as its keys to a file with cPickle Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I want to know How to save a dictionary containing utf-8 characters as its keys to a file in Python with `cPickle`? this dictionary is very large and I've heard that `cPickle` is much faster than `pickle`. Also I suppose having utf-8 encoded keys is also problematic.
Any other fast solutions are also welcome.
here is what I do and below is the error message:

```
unique_ngrams_dict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)# just to show how I defined my dict


dict_file = codecs.open('ngram_dict', 'w', 'utf-8')
cPickle.dump(unique_ngrams_dict,dict_file)
dict_file.close()
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Generate_NGram.py", line 81, in <module>
    save_ngram_dict(unique_ngrams_dict)
  File "Generate_NGram.py", line 70, in save_ngram_dict
    cPickle.dump(unique_ngrams_dict,dict_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle function objects
```

thanks

Comment: Why do you supposed utf8 keys are problematic?  Have you tried pickling it?

Comment: not really, but should I encode them when I want to write them in a file?

Comment: The TypeError you're getting seems to indicate that `uniq_ngrams_dict` is a function, not a dictionary.

Comment: I double checked it, it is indeed a defaultdict type

Comment: Some element within your dictionary is a function then.

Comment: would it be because it is a defaultdict, defined to have the value 0 for new keys automatically?

Comment: try pickling dict(unique_ngrams_dict)

Comment: i found the problem: "lambda" in my definition of dict acts as a functions. That's why i get a type error. I changed my code to unique_ngrams_dict = defaultdict(int) which solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pickle is a *binary* format, so you shouldn't open the file with any codecs, just:

   ```
   file('ngram_dict', 'w')
   ```

   It's not a reason it's failing, just quite inefficient.
2. The actual problem is the object you are trying to save contains a function reference
   (the default value `lambda: 0`) and pickle format does not support serializing functions.

   You'll have three options:

   1. Use a regular `dict` and use it's `.get` method with default argument.
   2. Set

      ```
      unique_ngrams_dict.default_factory = None
      ```

      before pickling and set it back to

      ```
      unique_ngrams_dict.default_factory = lambda: 0
      ```

      after unpickling.
   3. Define a class like:

      ```
      class NgramDefault:
          def __call__():
              return 0
      ```

      and use `NgramDefault()` as the default factory instead of `lambda: 0`.

Comment: apparently unique_ngrams_dict = defaultdict(int) should do the same

Comment: I think the file should be open like that file('ngram_dict', 'wb')

Answer (score 0):

You should just do it and trust the pickle module to do the right thing. The best way to treat pickle is as an opaque blob of stuff that will magically re-create the exact data structure you started with when you unpickle it.

Don't try to apply any sort of encoding to the output of pickle, it should be treated as a binary blob. If you have unicode elements when you pickle, they will be unicode once you unpickle.

Comment: is there any faster options? i mean in terms of writing/loading to/from file?

Comment: @Hossein - That's a completely different question than the one you asked. If you want to give an example of your data structure and ask the question "What's the fastest way to get this data structure into a file and back out again?", I'm sure you'd get some great answers.